# Log4J log path in a servlet (TOMCAT)

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I want to set up my log4j log path with a db param.
My log4j properties is this:

```
 log4j.appender.file.File=${log.app.path}/app/app1.log
```

I populated the System property ${log.app.path} with a JVM var.
Now I would like to set that path with a value in database. Than I thought to set it with a ServletContextListener but I found that the log4j is aready running.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always initialize a logger with a FileAppender in the code. You can just use the value you want( from db or where ever) and set the params for FileAppender in to the Logger Object.

Comment: Ok but it starts loggin in other place... it is difficiult to do not lost log record editing the path, am I right?

Comment: check how it logs somewer!.. if you provide a right path and if the path is write accessible that should  do the job

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the log4j jdbcappender ?

link is :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

Comment: No, but this is for logging into the db... i want a log in file but in a place defined in db.